# Push Notification dialog popping up erroneously in AIR for iOS app on iOS 8

Tags: ios, actionscript, air

I have an iOS app that was developed using the Flash IDE and AIR 4.0.0.1390 for iOS. When I installed it on a device with iOS 8, upon launch I received the dialog box that the app wanted to send push notifications. This did not happen when I installed the same app on iOS 7.

What's particularly weird is that I checked the provisioning profile and the App ID, and it says that push notifications are disabled for that app ID (it's a wildcard app ID). So I wonder if it is an issue with iOS 8 itself.

In any event, I'd like to figure out if there is a workaround to make sure that the app is not added to the notification center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your AIR version. AIR 4 is 9 months old now and as of last week, Apple is rejecting any apps missing iPhone 6/6 plus icons and will soon be rejecting apps not built through Xcode 6. Those things have been added in AIR 15, and I believe the notification dialog you are experiencing was fixed in the latest AIR 15 beta.

Comment: After updating to AIR 15 I kept seeing the notification center settings return when I reinstalled the app, but when I made a new version with a new app ID, that cleared it out.I had been afraid to jump to AIR 15 because I am right at the end of a dev cycle, but it seems to have been a smooth upgrade. Thanks!